# Pipenv libarchive error: no such file or directory: b'liblibarchive.a'

Tags: python, pipenv, libarchive

Installing libarchive using pipenv returned with a file/directory not found error.
The pip file contains the package as `libarchive==0.4.7`. Logs showing the error:

```
...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Verifying that the library is accessible.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Library can not be loaded: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibarchive.a'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'liblibarchive.a'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ----------------------------------------
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for libarchive
...
```

I'm using Python3.8 on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file was probably renamed. Creating a symbolic link to the renamed file fixed the issue:

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
ln -s -f libarchive.a liblibarchive.a
```